# Prolog: check if two lists have the same elements

Tags: list, prolog, non-termination, failure-slice

I am new to Prolog and I am having a problems checking if two lists have exactly the same elements. It is possible for the elements to be in different orders. I have this code:

```
myremove(X, [X|T], T).   
myremove(X, [H|T], [H|R]) :-
   myremove(X, T, R).

 same_elements([], []).
 same_elements([H1|T1], L2) :-      
    myremove(H1, L2, Nl2),  
    same_elements(T1, Nl2).
```

It works except that

```
?- same_elements([b,c,a], X).
```

causes an out of memory error after returning the first result. So then I tried to narrow down the result set by checking that the length of the lists are equal and checking that H1 is a member of L2:

```
mylength([], 0).
mylength([_|T], R) :-
   mylength(T, Nr),
   R is Nr+1.

mymember(X, [X|_]).
mymember(X, [_|T]) :-
   mymember(X, T).

same_elements([], []).
same_elements([H1|T1], L2) :- 
   mylength([H1|T1], X),
   mylength(L2, Y),
   Y = X,
   mymember(H1, L2),
   myremove(H1, L2, Nl2),
   same_elements(T1, Nl2).
```

Now both

```
?- same_elements([b,c,a], X).
?- same_elements(X, [b,c,a]).
```

return all of the results, but then they just hang at the end.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you could do with a builtin: `same_elements(X,Y) :- msort(X,S),msort(Y,S).`

Comment: I don't know why @false said my answer was a bad advice. Now I've deleted it. Anyway...do you know what's the use of [cut](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=!/0) in Prolog?

Comment: When I tried your suggestion same_elements([b,c,a], X) only returns one result, but I want all.

Comment: Yes, msort/2 is overkill, you shoud test if the argument is instantiated (with var(X)). But if you add a cut `myremove(X, [X|T], T) :- !.` your first attempt works in both ways.

Comment: @chac: See my answer: You suggested to change something outside the visible part. Therefore your cut will have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @false: actually, I tested and saw it working...

Comment: @chac: Please look at the failure slice below.  But to make it very clear: By adding a cut in myremove/3, the program loops just as before!

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: Yes.

But, before going into this, there is a more interesting question around: How did you find those problems? You must have been really lucky to find them! I tried:

```
?- same_elements([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],Xs).
   Xs = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
;  Xs = [a,b,c,d,e,g,f]
;  Xs = [a,b,c,d,f,e,g]
;  Xs = [a,b,c,d,g,e,f]
;  ... .
```

... and was only overwhelmed by the solutions produced. No, I did not have the patience to go through all answers. But there is a simpler way to test a concrete query: Simply remove the answers and only concentrate on whether or not the query stops.  To this end, I add the goal `false`:

```
?- same_elements([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],Xs), false.
```

Now, we will never see any solution. But we might observe the termination of the query. Alas, this query now probably loops. At least we no longer wade through irrelevant solutions.

To further narrow down the reason for non-termination, we will add `false` goals into your program. That modified program is called a **failure slice**. In this manner we try to narrow down the part that is responsible for non-termination. If we succeed in adding the `false` goals such that the program still does not terminate, we will have an excellent clue how to fix the problem. For example:

```
same_elements([], []).
same_elements([H1|T1], L2) :-
  mylength([H1|T1], X), false,
  mylength(L2, Y),
  Y = X,
  mymember(H1, L2),
  myremove(H1, L2, Nl2),
  same_elements(T1, Nl2).
```

So this is almost your program, except that there is a goal `false` in it. The goals behind `false` are striked through to make clear that they are irrelevant.

Now, the query terminates:

```
?- same_elements([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],Xs), false.
   false.
```

So, we removed too much already. Next try:

```
same_elements([], []).
same_elements([H1|T1], L2) :-
  mylength([H1|T1], X),
  mylength(L2, Y), false,
  Y = X,
  mymember(H1, L2),
  myremove(H1, L2, Nl2),
  same_elements(T1, Nl2).
```

Now, the query does not terminate!

That means: Don't look at the remaining parts of your program. Whatever is written there, cannot undo this loop!

So we can now ponder about the visible part: It does neither terminate for

```
?- same_elements([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],Xs).
```

nor for

```
?- same_elements(Xs,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]).
```

And the culprit is just this very tiny part of the program.

Your idea was to ensure that both lists are of same length.

Instead of using a length-predicate, define a new one:

```
list_same_length([], []).
list_same_length([_|Xs], [_|Ys]) :-
    list_same_length(Xs, Ys).
```

This now terminates for "both directions".

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that debugging technique and now my predicate terminates.

Comment: @CarolineM: You might also want to test for same length only once - and then use your original definition with both arguments being of same length.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
same(X, X).
same([A| B], [C| D]):-
    A=C,
    same(B,D).
```

it'll return true if they are the same. false otherwise.

Comment: you can omit the `A=C` check using `same([A| B], [A| D])`. But your solution won't work for this case as specifically mentioned: "It is possible for the elements to be in different orders".